# How do I end a hot observable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'd like to end the observable based on an event if a value is not received within a specific time-frame.

```
// This will go on forever because it is a hot
// observable based on an event
// If a value has not been produced in, say, 2 seconds
// I would like to stop it and raise an OnCompleted
var observable = Observable.FromEvent(...);
```

I could do a `TakeUntil` like so but that would be an absolute time period from the start of the subscription. What I want is, if a value has not been returned in, say, 2 seconds from the time the previous value was generated, then stop and raise an `OnCompleted` event.

If no value was ever generated by the observable for 2 seconds, then also stop and raise an `OnCompleted` event.

How would I do that without the client code having to maintain this state about what time the last value was generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = observable.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0), Observable.Empty<int>());
```

Just replace `int` with whatever type your source observable is.